# Retrieving CMSSignedData from ASN.1 encoding in Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, bouncycastle, asn.1, pkcs#7

In the following piece of code I sign a message using Bouncy Castle:

```
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignedDataGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSTypedData;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Base64;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;

public class Sign {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        String certPath = "certPath";
        FileInputStream inPublic = new FileInputStream(certPath);
        CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(inPublic);


        String keyPrivatePath = "keyPath";
        Path path = Paths.get(keyPrivatePath);
        Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(keyPrivatePath));
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(keyPrivatePath)));
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(spec);

        CMSProcessableByteArray msg = new CMSProcessableByteArray("My message".getBytes());
        CMSSignedDataGenerator sGen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();

        ContentSigner sha1Signer = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(privateKey);
        sGen.addSignerInfoGenerator(
                new JcaSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(
                        new JcaDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()
                ).build(sha1Signer, cert)
        );

        CMSSignedData sd = sGen.generate(msg);

        CMSTypedData cmsBytes = new CMSProcessableByteArray(sd.getEncoded());
        // How to reconstruct a CMSSignedData from cmsBytes again?
        byte[] bytes = (byte[]) cmsBytes.getContent();
        CMSSignedData retrieved = new CMSSignedData(bytes);
        System.out.println(retrieved.getSignedContent()); // Doesn't work, is null
    }
}
```

My question is how to retrieve the original `CMSSignedData` (wanting to read the original message, and verify it), using only the byte array of the ASN.1 encoding of this object.

The reason I am asking this, is that I want to decrypt a certain encrypted and signed message. I am able to decrypt this message, but it results in an ASN.1 encoded byte array (which does correspond to my original message), but I am not able to process this decrypted message any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the classes `org.bouncycastle.asn1.cms.ContentInfo` and `org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence`:

```
CMSTypedData cmsBytes = new CMSProcessableByteArray(sd.getEncoded());
byte[] bytes = (byte[]) cmsBytes.getContent();

// reconstruct CMSSignedData from the byte array
ContentInfo ci = ContentInfo.getInstance(ASN1Sequence.fromByteArray(bytes));
CMSSignedData sig = new CMSSignedData(ci);
```

Also note that you must create a `CMSSignedData` with the content encapsulated in the signature, so you must change this:

```
CMSSignedData sd = sGen.generate(msg);
```

To this:

```
CMSSignedData sd = sGen.generate(msg, true);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work :(
in this case, `sig.getSignedContent()` yields null, instead of the CMSProcessableByteArray of the message that I put in...

Comment: What versions are you using? I'm using BouncyCastle 1.57 and Java 1.7

Comment: bouncyCastle 1.57 and Java 1.8. Is it supposed to work for Java 1.7?

Comment: Have you checked if `getSignedContent` in your original `CMSSignedData` is null?

Comment: In the original CMSSignedData, it is `org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSProcessableByteArray@5cc7c2a6`. I am able to process it further to the original string I inputted.

Comment: I've made a test here, I think I know what's wrong. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Many Thanks Hugo! I greatly appreciate it :)

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked/solved your problem, or you found it helpful, you can accept the answer and/or upvote it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers